# What's wrong with my approach to converting a binary number to decimal via iterative addition and checking individual characters (see code)?

Tags: c++

I know this isn't a very advanced problem but this has been bugging me all day. I'm trying to convert a binary number to a decimal one. I'm trying to loop through a string which is the binary input and compare each individual character to '1'. If the character is '1' then the answer should increase by 2 to the power of the current index. But when I try, say "1010", the program will output 5 which is wrong it should be 10.

```cpp
cout << "Okay then, enter your binary number: ";
string binaryInput = "";
cin >> binaryInput;
int answer = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < binaryInput.length(); i++) {

    answer += (binaryInput[i] == '1') ? (pow(2.0, i)) : (0);

}

cout << "The generated decimal number is " << answer << "!\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should probably be "Learn how to use a debugger and step through the code to see what's wrong." but I have a good day so I'll allow you to use the longer way of asking here.

Lets take your example and see what happens in each iteration:

`i == 0;` `binaryInput[i] == '1';` `answer += 1;`

`i == 1;` `binaryInput[i] == '0';` `answer += 0;`

`i == 2;` `binaryInput[i] == '1';` `answer += 4;`

`i == 3;` `binaryInput[i] == '0';` `answer += 0;`

So you can see why the result is `5`.

The clever fix for this would be to replace. `answer += (binaryInput[i] == '1') ? (pow(2.0, i)) : (0);` with `answer <<= 1; answer |= binaryInput[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0;`.

I used operators `<<=` and `|=` to make it funnier.
Homework: learn what they do.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it, although I have no sense of humour so I would use `*=` and `+=`.

Comment: The really funny thing is that I've wrote that code for a question I'm just asking and it immediately became useful as an answer.

Comment: Whelp I got called out lol. Now I know why the debugger is powerfully useful. Also I have no clue what the replacement code does but I guess that's my hw

Answer (score 2):

The power increases from right to left and you are doing the opposite .it should go like this

```
int power=binaryInput.length();
for(int i = 0;i<binaryInput.length(); i++) {
power--;
answer += (binaryInput[i] == '1') ? (pow(2.0, power)) : (0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You read from left to right. You must read from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your powers the wrong way round, the lowest values of `i` have the highest powers, and vice versa. In other words this

```
answer += binaryInput[i] == '1' ? pow(2.0, binaryInput.length() - i - 1) : 0;
```